# Parameterization of the Hawaiian Earring

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I've been trying to find a way to parameterize the Hawaiian Earring, i.e. to find a parametric function $[0,1]\to\mathbb{H}$. I  would like this function to be continuous and differentiable.

So far I only know that I can express a circle of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ as $$t\mapsto \frac{1}{n}(\cos(2t\pi)+1,\sin(2t\pi))$$ but am struggling with finding a way to somehow cover all $n$'s with just one function.

I think that I should somehow express $n$ as $n(t)$, which would be a step function on smaller and smaller parts of the $[0,1]$ interval, but am very much stuck on how to do such a thing.

Would this kind of approach work for this? If so, any hints on how to proceed? Or should I be thinking about this in some other way?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k > 0$. The polar graph $r = e^{-k\theta} \cos\theta$, i.e.,
$$
x(t) = e^{-kt} \cos^{2} t,\quad
y(t) = e^{-kt} \cos t \sin t,\qquad \pi/2 < t < \infty,
$$
has the general shape of (i.e., the image is homeomorphic to) a Hawaiian earring made of circles. Evaluate at $t = \frac{\pi}{2} + s/(1 - s)$ to get a parametrization with $0 < s < 1$. (The curve with $k = 1/3$ is shown.)

If you must have circles, first pick a function such as $t = \pi/s$, which for each positive integer $n$ maps the interval $[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]$ to $[\pi n, \pi(n+1)]$, then do a piecewise definition of the type $(x, y) = \frac{1}{n}\sin t(\sin t, \cos t)$ for $\frac{1}{n+1} < s \leq \frac{1}{n}$.

[image: An approximate Hawaiian earring in polar coordinates]

Comment: Hey I would like to ask, how would you go about showing that the piecewise defined function is continuous? It looks to me that points around 0 could provide some difficulty?

Comment: And could a continuously differentiable parametrization be obtained in a similar way?